# Custom user authentication for specific screens in grails

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am using spring security core plugin in my grails application. but now I have a custom requirement.

I need to re-authenticate the user for some secret screens each time before opening these, even user is signed in already.

On re-authentication auth screen, I also want to add a secret pin code after username and password.

What will be the best way to implement this or is there any plugin available with this functionality ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't any plugin that would address this for you. However, Glen Smith [posted a few years ago](http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2010/01/15/hacking-custom-authentication-providers-with-grails-spring-security.html) how to implement your own custom authentication for specific URIs using the Grails Spring Security core plugin.

What he outlines there is very similar to what you will need to do:

1. Create a custom authentication object to hold the request.
2. Create a custom authentication provider to authenticate the request.
3. Create a custom security filter to apply to your URIs.

You should also note Burt's comment on the mentioned post about how to register custom authentication filters. This eliminates some of the code Glen provided.

Your implementation will be slightly more complex since you will need an additional filter to catch an authentication failure and route the user to the special login page. This is where things get quite tricky, but with the information above you should be able to get started and ask questions as you hit roadblocks.

Comment: I resolved this problem with the combination of annotations and filters